# React - Material-UI Modal causing an error with the tabindex

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am getting this error when I open a modal on my React app but I can't figure out what it means or how to fix it.

"*Warning: Material-UI: the modal content node does not accept focus.
For the benefit of assistive technologies, the tabIndex of the node is being set to "-1".*"

```
<SettingsModal event={this.state.eventDetails} id={this.state.eventDetails.id} delete={this.handleRemoveEvent}/>
```

returns:

```
return(
  <>
    <Paper className={classes.SettingsModal}>
        <h1>{this.props.event.name}</h1>
        <p>{this.props.event.description}</p>
        <p>{this.props.event.id}</p>
        <Button onClick={(e) => this.props.delete(this.props.event)}>Delete Event</Button>
    </Paper>
  </>
);
```

Comment: You have to include your code in this type of question. But I think the answer is here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9775 , specifically `A tabIndex: -1 on PaperProps did the trick`

Comment: ok I added the code to the question. Where would I add a tabIndex in that?

Answer (score 6):

I've found fix! To remove this error you should wrap your Modal content with DialogContent component like this

```
import DialogContent from '@material-ui/core/DialogContent';
// ...
render () {
    return (
       <Modal open={this.state.modalOpened} onClose={() => this.setState({ modalOpened: false, modalContent: null })}>
                <DialogContent>
                    {this.state.modalContent}
                </DialogContent>
            </Modal>
    );
}
```

Comment: In MUI 5.4.0, the import path is different:
`import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';`

Comment: DialogContent may add things you don't want, simply add tabIndex={-1} on the first component inside the modal is the right answer

Answer (score 4):

i had the same problem. apparently wrapping a div around SettingsModal should fix it.

Answer (score 4):

All the credit goes to @Idos's comment above since he found the reference to the [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9775). I found that [this specific comment was](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9775#issuecomment-419089341)  useful.

The wrapping element of the Modal Contents needs to have a prop of
`tabIndex: {-1}`

In your case looks like you need to do the following:

```
return(
  <Paper tabIndex:{-1} ...>
...
  </Paper>
);
```

Comment: this works to me

Answer (score 2):

Following @Wolfman comment, I just used Fragment from React, because it doesn't add any DOM element:

```
render () {
    return (
       <Modal open={this.state.modalOpened} onClose={() => this.setState({ modalOpened: false, modalContent: null })}>
                <>
                    {this.state.modalContent}
                </>
            </Modal>
    );
}
```

Even though, I still don't understand that issue :/