# Material UI Dialog throwing errors in Storyshot tests due to ReactDOM.createPortal/react-test-renderer workarounds

Tags: material-ui, storybook, react-dom, react-test-renderer, storyshots

```
"@material-ui/core": "4.12.3"
"@storybook/addon-storyshots": "6.3.12",
"@storybook/react": "6.3.12",
"react": "17.0.2",
```

Cannot use Dialog in a Storybook Storyshots test without errors, because the [workarounds to get ReactDOM.createPortal and react-test-renderer](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11565#issuecomment-368877149) to work together, causes the Material UI Dialog to throw console warnings in the tests.

I can workaround the first issue by either using the `disablePortal` property within Dialog stories or by mocking it out like this in testSetup:

```
jest.mock("react-dom", () => ({
    ...jest.requireActual("react-dom"),
    createPortal: (children: ReactNode) => children,
}));
```

Both these workarounds create a second issue, which is for every story that contains a Dialog we get a console warning creating a huge amount of noise in the test output.

"*Warning: Material-UI: the modal content node does not accept focus. For the benefit of assistive technologies, the tabIndex of the node is being set to "-1".*"

I have checked for duplicates and have several related issues like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951479/react-material-ui-modal-causing-an-error-with-the-tabindex), however, it's not the same as the actual Dialogs and Storybooks work fine with no errors and are composed properly with an internal focusable `DialogContent`. This issue is *only* affecting the storyshot tests when the portal is mocked or bypassed.

If I add the `disableAutoFocus` property to each Dialog within the Storybooks, the console warnings go away, however it seems like a hack.
Does anyone know why these warnings are appearing or a better way to resolve this?

Thanks