# MUI Modal/Popover/Drawer don't allow Usersnap to register input

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, gatsby

I use MUI v4 in my react gastby app and integrated Usersnap with gatsby-base.js using

```
import React from 'react'
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'

// Replace with the API keys from your widget installation page
const USERSNAP_GLOBAL_API_KEY = '<YOUR_USERSNAP_GLOBAL_API_KEY>'

/* Render this anywhere in your tree (preferably at the top of your app) to invoke the usersnap widget.
 */
const UserSnap = () => {
  return (
    <Helmet>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        {`
          window.onUsersnapCXLoad = function(api) {
            api.init();
          }
          var script = document.createElement('script');
          script.defer = 1;
          script.src = 'https://widget.usersnap.com/global/load/${USERSNAP_GLOBAL_API_KEY}?onload=onUsersnapCXLoad';
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
      `}
      </script>
    </Helmet>
  )
}

export default UserSnap
```

and then import UserSnap.jsx in gatsby-config.js

```
import React from 'react'
import UserSnap from './src/wherever'

/* This is how to use with gatsby... this wraps every page component to include UserSnap.
 * Depending on your setup you may also need do the same in gatsby-browser.js 
 */
export const wrapPageElement = ({ element }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <UserSnap />
      {element}
    </>
  )
}
```

The usersnap mode removes focus from it's input whenever a modal or similar component is open but works fine otherwise.

[head tag continuously keeps flashing whenever Usersnap is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxYUQ.png)

Found a workaround to deal with modals by wrapping the block in a react fragment like this

```
<>
   <Modal
     open={open}
     className={classes.root}
     closeAfterTransition
     onClose={handleCancel}
   >
     <Fade in={open}>
       <Container maxWidth="md" className={classes.container}>
         <Paper className={classes.paper}>
           <AssumptionsEditor
             onCancel={handleCancel}
             onSave={handleSave}
             {...rest}
           />
         </Paper>
       </Container>
     </Fade>
   </Modal>
</>
```

but that's not the ideal solution and doesn't work on popover and drawer.
Help please?

Comment: Possible related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53951479/react-material-ui-modal-causing-an-error-with-the-tabindex